# How do I select the last non-empty value for a given ID and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to select the last value in a column that isn't blank (not non-null technically) and select it for every date after, until that value changes, then select that value and so on.

*What I have:*

| company_id | date | sales_stage | previous_sales_stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00.000 | a | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-19 00:00:00.000 | b | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-18 00:00:00.000 | c | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-17 00:00:00.000 | c | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00.000 | c | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-15 00:00:00.000 | d | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-14 00:00:00.000 | d | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-13 00:00:00.000 | d | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-12 00:00:00.000 | e | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00.000 | e | NULL |

*What I'd like to have:*

| company_id | date | sales_stage | previous_sales_stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00.000 | a | b |
| 1 | 2022-05-19 00:00:00.000 | b | c |
| 1 | 2022-05-18 00:00:00.000 | c | d |
| 1 | 2022-05-17 00:00:00.000 | c | d |
| 1 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00.000 | c | d |
| 1 | 2022-05-15 00:00:00.000 | d | e |
| 1 | 2022-05-14 00:00:00.000 | d | e |
| 1 | 2022-05-13 00:00:00.000 | d | e |
| 1 | 2022-05-12 00:00:00.000 | e | NULL |
| 1 | 2022-05-11 00:00:00.000 | e | NULL |

This is going in a summary table that is shared with all companies ( so there will be multiple company ids and stages for a given date) and is calculated daily from a stored proc. If there is no value, `NULL` is okay.

Here is some T-SQL to create a temp table that recreates this example :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #blah

    CREATE TABLE #blah
(
    company_id INT
  , [date] DATETIME
  , sales_stage VARCHAR(50)
  , previous_sales_stage VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'a',CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'b',dateadd(d,-1,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'c',dateadd(d,-2,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'c',dateadd(d,-3,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'c',dateadd(d,-4,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'d',dateadd(d,-5,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'d',dateadd(d,-6,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'d',dateadd(d,-7,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'e',dateadd(d,-8,cast(getdate() as date)))
INSERT INTO #blah (company_id, sales_stage, [date]) VALUES (1,'e',dateadd(d,-9,cast(getdate() as date)))


SELECT * FROM #blah

UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'b' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-20 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'c' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-19 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'd' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-18 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'd' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-17 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'd' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-16 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'e' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-15 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'e' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-14 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = 'e' WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-13 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = NULL WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-12 00:00:00.000'
UPDATE #blah SET previous_sales_stage = NULL WHERE company_id = 1 AND date = '2022-05-11 00:00:00.000'

SELECT * FROM #blah
```

Comment: This is known as a "gaps and islands" problem.

Comment: Your markdown tables and your DML don't appear to match; there are no `NULL` values in `sales_stage` in your DML and the values in `previous_sales_stage` are completely different.

Comment: @Larnu, there will be no nulls in sales_stage, only empty string. But, previous_sales_stage can be NULL, since there will be no value for the day before the first value.

Comment: So what is the markdown table *"What I have"*? It isn't the data in your table `#blah`. How can you *"select the last non-null"* when there are no `NULL` values? The *last* non-`NULL` value if there are no `NULL` values, is the current row's value...

Comment: @Larnu, sorry for the confusion. The provided tsql is not a copy of the markdown table, rather a separate example that you can work from in SSMS. I should have said non-empty  instead of non-null.

Comment: The data still isn't reflective though. Providing DDL and DML is great, but it's useless if it isn't reflective of the problem you gave. Either amend the markdown tables to reflect the DDL and DML, or the DDL and DML to reflect the markdown tables.

Comment: @Larnu, markdown tables now reflect DDL/DML 1:1

Comment: Does `sales_stage` always have an decreasing value, or can it go back to a prior value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244907/discussion-between-ben-raymond-and-larnu).

Comment: @Larnu sales_stage can go to any value on any day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery or an OUTER APPLY, like this:

```
SELECT t1.company_id, t1.date, t1.sales_stage, x.previous_sales_stage
FROM #blah t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.sales_stage AS previous_sales_stage
    FROM #blah t2 
    WHERE t2.company_id=t1.company_id
        AND t2.date<t1.date
        AND t2.sales_stage<>t1.sales_stage
    ORDER BY t2.date DESC
) x
```